# How to calculate valence factor (n-factor) for a element?

Tags: stoichiometry, oxidation-state, mole

Suppose I am given some reaction in which 
$$\ce{C6H12O6 -> CO2}$$
and I want to calculate n-factor for this reaction to ultimately calculate equivalent weight of carbon for this reaction. Since $$E=\frac{M}{n}$$
I know that n-factor is no of electron gained/lost by one atom of a compound.

So Initial Oxidation state of carbon is $$6x + 12-12=0$$ $$x=0$$ meaning 
and final oxidation state of carbon is $$-4$$ Hence, n-factor of this reaction should be $4$ but it's given to be $28$. How is this possible? Can someone explain how to correctly calculate n-factor with few more examples?

Comment: How did you get the 2 of **2x+...** ?

Comment: Sorry for typo .

Comment: Are you sure its 28 and not 24?

Comment: Not sure , I could be wrong.

Comment: You say _it's given to be 28_. Is it given 28 on some website/text?

Comment: It was 28 in my notes , I may have made mistake .

Comment: answer is 24. 4*6=24.the ans provided by ur notes is wrong
the oxidation no. of carbon on product side is 4 and the no. of carbon atom on reactant side is 6.so n-factor of C 6*4=24

Comment: while balancing, you should take oxidation number on both sides, not the oxidation states. On the right, you will have 6CO2, so, ON=6*4=24. On the right, you have zero. So, n factor=24

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint :

n-factor of a molecule/compound is defined as the change in oxidation state **per molecule**.
You have correctly calculated the change of **one** carbon atom as 4.
But how many carbon atoms are there in the glucose molecule?

Note:

- The **average** oxidation state of carbon in glucose is zero while in reality the different carbons have different OS. ([Reference](http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/pshapley/GenChem2/B7/1.html))
- n-factor of a reaction is not defined but it is defined for a single species participating in that reaction.
- n-factor of glucose is not equal to the n-factor of the product formed in that reaction, that is, $\ce{CO_2}$.

Comment: And I differ from the answer provided by your notes. If I am wrong somewhere, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Okay what if we had 2 carbon atom on product side?

Comment: Hypothetically let's suppose c2o4

Comment: @Heisenberg The OS of Carbon in $C_2O_4$ is the same as in $CO_2$. Hence the n-factor **with respect to** _glucose_ shall remain the same.

Comment: atomicity of only reactant? is multiplied ?

Comment: Yes @Heisenberg. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your reaction, $\ce{C6H12O6 -> CO2}$ is a redox half-reaction. The *n*-factor of a molecule/compound in a redox reaction is defined as the change in the oxidation state per molecule (as defined in Del Pate's answer). The easy to visualize definition is the amount of electrons (in $\pu{mol}$) donate or accepted per $\pu{1 mol}$ of the compound in the given redox half-reaction.

> Can someone explain how to correctly calculate n-factor with few more examples?

Let's look at following redox half-reactions and find the *n*-factor by these two different definitions:

$$\text{Example 1:} \qquad \qquad  \ce{MnO4- ->[acid] Mn^2+ }$$

The oxidation number of $\ce{Mn}$ of the reactant is $+7$ while that of the product is $+2$. The change in the oxidation state per $\ce{MnO4-}$ is $+5$. Thus, the *n*-factor of $\ce{MnO4-}$ is $5$ in acid medium.

If we balance this redox half-reaction, we get:

$$\ce{MnO4- + 8 H+ + 5 e- -> Mn^2+ + 4 H2O}$$

Thus, the amount of electrons accepted per $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{MnO4-}$ in the given redox half-reaction is $5$. Hence, the *n*-factor of $\ce{MnO4-}$ is $5$ in acid medium.

$$\ce{MnO4- ->[base/neutral] Mn^4+ \ (\text{as} MnO2)}$$

The oxidation number of $\ce{Mn}$ of the reactant is $+7$ while that of the product is $+4$. The change in the oxidation state per $\ce{MnO4-}$ is $+3$. Thus, the *n*-factor of $\ce{MnO4-}$ is $3$ in base/neutral medium.

$$\ce{MnO4- + 2 H2O + 3 e- -> MnO2 + 4 OH-}$$

Thus, the amount of electrons accepted per $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{MnO4-}$ in the given redox half-reaction is $3$. Hence, the *n*-factor of $\ce{MnO4-}$ is $3$ in base/neutral medium.

$$\text{Example 2:} \qquad \qquad \ce{CuS -> Cu^2+ + SO2 }$$

The oxidation number of $\ce{S}$ of the reactant is $-2$ while that of the product is $+4$. The change in the oxidation state per $\ce{CuS}$ is $+6$. Thus, the *n*-factor of $\ce{CuS}$ is $5$ in this redox reaction.

If we balance this redox half-reaction, we get:

$$\ce{CuS + 2 H2O -> Cu^2+ + SO2 + 4 H+ + 6 e- }$$

Thus, the amount of electrons accepted per $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{CuS}$ in the given redox half-reaction is $6$. Hence, the *n*-factor of $\ce{CuS}$ is $6$ in this redox half-reaction.

Now, let's look at the given reaction in the question:

$$\ce{C6H12O6 -> CO2}$$

Suppose we don't know the oxidation number of $\ce{C}$ of glucose $(\ce{C6H12O6})$ since there are $\ce{6C}$s in the molecule. Thus, we can approach to solve the problem by the second method. If we balance this redox half-reaction, we get:

$$\ce{C6H12O6 + 6 H2O -> 6CO2 + 24 H+ + 24 e- }$$

Thus, the amount of electrons accepted per $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{C6H12O6}$ in the given redox half-reaction is $24$. Hence, the *n*-factor of $\ce{C6H12O6}$ is $24$ in this redox half-reaction. This demonstration reveals that even without knowing the change in oxidation number during the reaction, you can find the *n*-factor.

**Note:** This finding shows that the given answer for the question is incorrect.